# Advantage of libSVM over CvSvm

Tags: opencv, svm, libsvm

I'm already working with CvSVM (SVM available in openCV ). Can someone point out some advantages using libSVM for training rather than using CvSvm ?

( I'm using MS Visual Studio 2010)

Or else, should I continue working with CvSvm ?

Comment: CvSVM is a opencv wrapper around libSVM .

Comment: thank you for the reply ! Does that mean it's ok to continue working with CvSvm ? I mean, with SVM support in openCV ?

Comment: as long as you're happy with the opencv interface, - sure.